# Volume of solid using double integration.

Tags: integration

A lemniscate with equation $r^2=2a^2\cos(2\theta)$ is bounded above by the sphere $z=(2a^2-r^2)^{1/2}$. In setting up the double integral to find the volume. I'm using $r$ from $0$ to $a(2cos(2\theta))^{1/2}$ and theta from $\tfrac14\pi$ to $-\tfrac14\pi$. Am I any where close to the correct setup?

Comment: Are you sure of the equation? The equation of a lemniscate is $r^2=2a^2\cos(2 \theta)$.  And, can you clarify what is the searched volume ?

Comment: Yes Emilio, it is meant to be cos2(theta). The limit is also meant to be cos2(theta).

Comment: OK. I edit...but what is the volume you are looking for?

Comment: The volume is both lobes up to the sphere.